# How can I make UI for matrices in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm developing a mathematical app in Flutter which will solve mathematics problems like matrices, equations etc. I'm getting issues in the UI.

[How can I make this UI for matrices in Flutter.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW1JW.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Thank for replaying. I have solved some of the matrices for addition, subtraction and multiplication in dart but I need to make UI for matrices so I can call those functions and solve the matrices entered by user.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look into gridview: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html

As for the parentheses, here are some packages for math symbols:

https://pub.dev/packages/catex

https://pub.dev/packages/math_keyboard

Or just use text widgets with some parantheses inside

Comment: Thanks for answering. How can I use GridView to achieve such UI?